# Cannot populate django generated form in html template

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to use django's form module to create and display a form. The following code I have executes without errors but an HTML form is not populated. 
I have made sure that I am loading correct template. I also am certain that correct view is triggered when I go to a certain URL. I am posting some relevant code below from views, model, forms, and template files. I did debugging for quite a bit by trial-and-error but could not get to the root of issue.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from app.forms import RegistrationForm

def registration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('register.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

register.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<form action="/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app.models import Agent

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField( label=(u'User Name'), required=True )
    first_name = forms.CharField( label=(u'First Name'), required=True )
    last_name = forms.CharField( label=(u'Last Name'), required=True )
    birthday = forms.DateField( label=(u'Date of birth'), required=True )
    email = forms.EmailField( label=(u'Email Address'), required=True )
    password = forms.CharField( label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), required=True )
    password_confirm = forms.CharField( label=(u'Confirm Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), required=True )

    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        #exclude = ['username',]

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken, please select another.")

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password_confirm']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords did not match.  Please try again.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Agent(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name
```

Comment: Verify you have `"content"` block in _base.html_, or show us that file.

Comment: When you say that the form is not populated, do you mean that the form fields show up, but are not populated with any values? Or are you trying to say you do not see the form fields?

Comment: What do you mean, "populated"? With what data? You're not passing any data to the form, so I don't know what you're expecting it to be populated with.

Comment: I meant form itself is not populated. I had to add ref to content block in base.html. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Had to add content block ref in base.html

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```